# ODBC connection failed

Tags: mysql, r

i never had problems to connect my databas with R, but i had a problem with my ODBC drivers on my laptop so they were installed again. now i can't make a database connection in R anymore... can someone help me?

I installed RODBC  in R, i want to connect to DB2 database.
i use:

```
library(RODBC)

myconn<- odbcConnect("DSN", uid = "USERID", pwd = "PASSWORD")
```

then i received this error:

> Warning messages:
>
> 1: In RODBC::odbcDriverConnect("DSN=DSN4;UID=USERID;PWD=PASSWORD") :
>   [RODBC] ERROR: state IM004, code 0, message [Microsoft][ODBC Driver
>   Manager] Driver's SQLAllocHandle on SQL_HANDLE_ENV failed
>
> 2: In RODBC::odbcDriverConnect("DSN=DSN4;UID=USERID;PWD=PASSWORD") :
>   ODBC connection failed

what to do? i never had this problem.

Comment: it looks like your drivers aren't correctly linked. Do the information `"DSN", uid = "USERID", pwd = "PASSWORD"` are the same as in your driver ?

Comment: yes they are the same